# How to revert to the default Team Site icon after setting an image file

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-logo

I've managed to add an image as a site icon for a sub-site, although the scaling algorithm didn't behave as expected and only the middle of a wide logo appears.
That in turn seems to have also set all the config screens to black on black. The pages users can navigate to appear fine with the site logo partially visible. 
O365 SP will now not let me save a different icon that I scaled manually, and I can't seem to remove it or set it back to the default. It's not an option under look & feel, change the look or site information screens (see screenshots).

Help.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check under Title, Description and logo and remove it.

Comment: Can you go to this url `https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx` and remove it from there ?

Answer (score 1):

After settings a image:
[image]

You can go to Site Settings > Title, Description, and Logo. Delete the checked part of the image below and leave it blank. 
[image]

Click "OK" and it will revert to the default Team Site icon. 
[image]